# Oracle SQL Query to Select Latest Employee Entries Per Each Hour

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

How would I modify the following SQL query code to return the latest entry of each employee per hour, instead of currently returning every occurrence from each employee regardless of how many times it appears in the query per each hour.

I've attached example data for the order of what currently would be in the database and the desired table output. Note: you can see it's in descending order and 2 entries (0001 and 0009) are omitted because they came from the same employees within an hour interval.

SQL Query Code:

```
select
     TRANSACTION_ID
     EMPLOYEE_ID
     FIRST_NAME
     LAST_NAME
     TIME_STAMP
from (select d.*,
             row_number() over (partition by EMPLOYEE_ID, trunc(TIME_STAMP, 'HH') order by TIME_STAMP desc) as SEQNUM
      from MAIN.DATABASE d
     ) d
where SEQNUM = 1;
order by TRANSACTION_ID desc;
```

This is the current order of the data in the database:

| TRANSACTION_ID | EMPLOYEE_ID | FIRST_NAME | LAST_NAME | TIME_STAMP |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0001 | AAAA | Adam | Akbar | 10/05/2021 04:42:42.000 PM |
| 0004 | BBBB | Barry | Brink | 10/06/2021 07:25:25.000 AM |
| 0003 | CCCC | Charlie | Che | 10/06/2021 07:15:15.000 AM |
| 0005 | DDDD | David | Doe | 10/06/2021 07:27:27.000 AM |
| 0006 | EEEE | Eric | Erickson | 10/06/2021 07:29:29.000 AM |
| 0007 | FFFF | Fred | Foe | 10/06/2021 07:31:31.000 AM |
| 0008 | GGGG | George | Guy | 10/06/2021 07:33:33.000 AM |
| 0010 | HHHH | Henry | Hugh | 10/06/2021 07:55:55.000 AM |
| 0009 | HHHH | Henry | Hugh | 10/06/2021 07:54:54.000 AM |
| 0002 | AAAA | Adam | Akbar | 10/05/2021 04:43:43.000 PM |

This is what should be returned:

| TRANSACTION_ID | EMPLOYEE_ID | FIRST_NAME | LAST_NAME | TIME_STAMP |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0010 | HHHH | Henry | Hugh | 10/06/2021 07:55:55.000 AM |
| 0008 | GGGG | George | Guy | 10/06/2021 07:33:33.000 AM |
| 0007 | FFFF | Fred | Foe | 10/06/2021 07:31:31.000 AM |
| 0006 | EEEE | Eric | Erickson | 10/06/2021 07:29:29.000 AM |
| 0005 | DDDD | David | Doe | 10/06/2021 07:27:27.000 AM |
| 0004 | BBBB | Barry | Brink | 10/06/2021 07:25:25.000 AM |
| 0003 | CCCC | Charlie | Che | 10/06/2021 07:15:15.000 AM |
| 0002 | AAAA | Adam | Akbar | 10/05/2021 04:43:43.000 PM |

However, this is what the code is currently returning as written:

| TRANSACTION_ID | EMPLOYEE_ID | FIRST_NAME | LAST_NAME | TIME_STAMP |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0010 | HHHH | Henry | Hugh | 10/06/2021 07:55:55.000 AM |
| 0006 | EEEE | Eric | Erickson | 10/06/2021 07:29:29.000 AM |
| 0003 | CCCC | Charlie | Che | 10/06/2021 07:15:15.000 AM |
| 0002 | AAAA | Adam | Akbar | 10/05/2021 04:43:43.000 PM |

Any idea what I'm missing and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The query ( in order to return what you want ) should work as this. However., I am assuming your field `time_stamp` is really a timestamp in the format you provided.

```
SQL> set lines 220
SQL> with x ( transaction_id , employee_id, first_name, last_name, time_stamp )
  2  as
  3  (
  4  select '0001' , 'AAAA', 'Adam'       , 'Akbar'     , to_timestamp('10/05/2021 04:42:42.000 PM','MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS.FF3 PM') from dual union all
  5  select '0004' , 'BBBB', 'Barry'      , 'Brink'     , to_timestamp('10/06/2021 07:25:25.000 AM','MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS.FF3 AM') from dual union all
  6  select '0003' , 'CCCC', 'Charlie' , 'Che'      , to_timestamp('10/06/2021 07:15:15.000 AM','MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS.FF3 AM') from dual union all
  7  select '0005' , 'DDDD', 'David'      , 'Doe'           , to_timestamp('10/06/2021 07:27:27.000 AM','MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS.FF3 AM') from dual union all
  8  select '0006' , 'EEEE', 'Eric'       , 'Erickson'  , to_timestamp('10/06/2021 07:29:29.000 AM','MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS.FF3 AM') from dual union all
  9  select '0007' , 'FFFF', 'Fred'       , 'Foe'           , to_timestamp('10/06/2021 07:31:31.000 AM','MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS.FF3 AM') from dual union all
 10  select '0008' , 'GGGG', 'George'  , 'Guy'      , to_timestamp('10/06/2021 07:33:33.000 AM','MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS.FF3 AM') from dual union all
 11  select '0010' , 'HHHH', 'Henry'      , 'Hugh'          , to_timestamp('10/06/2021 07:55:55.000 AM','MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS.FF3 AM') from dual union all
 12  select '0009' , 'HHHH', 'Henry'      , 'Hugh'          , to_timestamp('10/06/2021 07:54:54.000 AM','MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS.FF3 AM') from dual union all
 13  select '0002' , 'AAAA', 'Adam'       , 'Akbar'         , to_timestamp('10/05/2021 04:43:43.000 PM','MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS.FF3 PM') from dual
 14  )
 15  select
 16       TRANSACTION_ID ,
 17       EMPLOYEE_ID    ,
 18       FIRST_NAME     ,
 19       LAST_NAME      ,
 20       TIME_STAMP
 21  from (select x.*,
 22               row_number() over (partition by EMPLOYEE_ID, trunc(TIME_STAMP, 'HH') order by TIME_STAMP desc) as SEQNUM
 23        from x
 24       )
 25  where SEQNUM = 1
 26* order by TRANSACTION_ID desc

TRAN EMPL FIRST_N LAST_NAM TIME_STAMP
---- ---- ------- -------- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
0010 HHHH Henry   Hugh     06-OCT-21 07.55.55.000000000 AM
0008 GGGG George  Guy      06-OCT-21 07.33.33.000000000 AM
0007 FFFF Fred    Foe      06-OCT-21 07.31.31.000000000 AM
0006 EEEE Eric    Erickson 06-OCT-21 07.29.29.000000000 AM
0005 DDDD David   Doe      06-OCT-21 07.27.27.000000000 AM
0004 BBBB Barry   Brink    06-OCT-21 07.25.25.000000000 AM
0003 CCCC Charlie Che      06-OCT-21 07.15.15.000000000 AM
0002 AAAA Adam    Akbar    05-OCT-21 04.43.43.000000000 PM

8 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query is:

- missing commas between the terms in the `SELECT` clause; and
- has a `;` after the `WHERE` filter and before the `ORDER BY` clause.

If you fix those issues then you get the code:

```sql
select TRANSACTION_ID,
       EMPLOYEE_ID,
       FIRST_NAME,
       LAST_NAME,
       TIME_STAMP
from   (
  select d.*,
         row_number() over (
           partition by EMPLOYEE_ID, trunc(TIME_STAMP, 'HH')
           order by TIME_STAMP desc
         ) as SEQNUM
  from   MAIN.DATABASE d
) d
where  SEQNUM = 1
order by TRANSACTION_ID desc;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE main.database (TRANSACTION_ID, EMPLOYEE_ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, TIME_STAMP ) AS
SELECT '0001', 'AAAA', 'Adam',    'Akbar',    TIMESTAMP '2021-05-10 16:42:42.000' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '0004', 'BBBB', 'Barry',   'Brink',    TIMESTAMP '2021-06-10 07:25:25.000' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '0003', 'CCCC', 'Charlie', 'Che',      TIMESTAMP '2021-06-10 07:15:15.000' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '0005', 'DDDD', 'David',   'Doe',      TIMESTAMP '2021-06-10 07:27:27.000' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '0006', 'EEEE', 'Eric',    'Erickson', TIMESTAMP '2021-06-10 07:29:29.000' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '0007', 'FFFF', 'Fred',    'Foe',      TIMESTAMP '2021-06-10 07:31:31.000' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '0008', 'GGGG', 'George',  'Guy',      TIMESTAMP '2021-06-10 07:33:33.000' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '0010', 'HHHH', 'Henry',   'Hugh',     TIMESTAMP '2021-06-10 07:55:55.000' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '0009', 'HHHH', 'Henry',   'Hugh',     TIMESTAMP '2021-06-10 07:54:54.000' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '0002', 'AAAA', 'Adam',    'Akbar',    TIMESTAMP '2021-05-10 16:43:43.000' FROM DUAL;
```

Works as expected:

> | TRANSACTION_ID | EMPLOYEE_ID | FIRST_NAME | LAST_NAME | TIME_STAMP |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 0010 | HHHH | Henry | Hugh | 10-JUN-21 07.55.55.000000000 |
> | 0008 | GGGG | George | Guy | 10-JUN-21 07.33.33.000000000 |
> | 0007 | FFFF | Fred | Foe | 10-JUN-21 07.31.31.000000000 |
> | 0006 | EEEE | Eric | Erickson | 10-JUN-21 07.29.29.000000000 |
> | 0005 | DDDD | David | Doe | 10-JUN-21 07.27.27.000000000 |
> | 0004 | BBBB | Barry | Brink | 10-JUN-21 07.25.25.000000000 |
> | 0003 | CCCC | Charlie | Che | 10-JUN-21 07.15.15.000000000 |
> | 0002 | AAAA | Adam | Akbar | 10-MAY-21 16.43.43.000000000 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=ffb1c7d58a33f18e584f667e70dea3ec)*

Comment: Hi MT0, thank you for your response. I made those corrections, however, the query was returning 0 entries. I realized that this was because SEQNUM = 2 in this scenario for the correct entries (SEQNUM = 3 for the entries we want discarded), but in other datasets good SEQNUM entries = 1 (and bad SEQNUM entries = 2).

Do you know a way to incorporate a [MAX(SEQNUM) - 1] variable in this code to standardize this code for any situation?